# Wordpress Twenty Seventeen dynamic navigation menu

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I'm just starting to wrap my head around the insane complexity of Wordpress and I don't have an example yet. I'm wondering how the theme Twenty Seventeen achieved the dynamic navigation bar where it moves to the bottom, leaving space for the front page video. On other pages it stays on the top accompanied by a banner image. Looking through the source code of header.php and front-page.php, I cannot find anything relevant to this.

As I understand the navigation menu needs to be in the header, however, the header also includes the head of the page and after it comes the menu. How is it inserting additional content before the menu?

Least I can do is [link the source code on GitHub.](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 31 of [header.php](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/5b5e4e86c2b8343863d7633758987da93c2bf2e8/header.php) adds the header image before the navigation bar.

Looking at the page source, you'll see that the `site-navigation-fixed` class is added to the navigation when you scroll down. That class is used to stick the navigation bar to the top of the page and is added with the `adjustScrollClass` function in the [global.js file](https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/c36810ca013e58f114eca61fd831a900427a7a6b/assets/js/global.js#L44).